# Add CSS Class to Sphinx Table Cell

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there a way to add a CSS class to a Sphinx-generated HTML table?  For example, I want to modify the following RST table definition:

```
+-------+
| cell1 |
+-------+
| cell2 |
+-------+
```

To generate the following HTML (roughly):

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>cell1</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="someClass">cell2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The following RST adds the specified class to a new paragraph element within the cell (instead of on the cell itself):

```
+--------------------------+
| cell1                    |
+--------------------------+
| .. rst-class:: someClass |
| cell2                    |
+--------------------------+
```

Is there any way to modify the original RST source to generate the specified HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of December 2023, all major desktop and mobile browsers support the [CSS `has` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).  This enables applying the style to the paragraph element, then writing CSS such as:

```
td:has(>.someClass) {
    /* Some style to apply to the td here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no way to do this in standard rST.

The ["class" directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class) ("rst-class" in Sphinx) sets the classes attribute value on its content or on the *first immediately following non-comment document-tree element*. As table cells are nested in table row elements, there is no way to pass a class argument value to cells in the first column.

As a workaround, you may use

```
+--------------------------+
| cell1                    |
|                          |
| .. rst-class:: someClass |
+--------------------------+
| cell2                    |
+--------------------------+
```

to get "someclass" on the second table row element and use the
`tr.someclass:first-child:` selector for CSS styling.

Note that class values are [normalized](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#identifier-normalization).

Comment: I upvoted, but didn't mark as answer because this wouldn't enable adding a class to the first row, or differentiating between cells in the same row.  However, note that all browsers released since December 2023 support the `has` CSS selector, so this question is really OBE.